# RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by

Tags: hooks

New to Drupal, I just created a new custom module in Drupal 9 to see how it works I was trying to test with a minimal piece of code. I just enable this module and got this error, now I can't open anything and getting this error on every page nothing is happening even if I change anything in code. This is my custom module code.

#### check_hookcalls.info.yml

```yaml
name: hook calls checking
description: module for testing hooks
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
type: module
```

#### check_hookcalls.module

```php
<?php

function check_hookcalls_node_presave() {
  die;
}

?>
```

The error I get is the following one.

> [13-Jul-2021 15:34:49 Europe/Berlin] RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by
> "C:\softwares\xampp\htdocs\d9_firstexperience\2\modules\check_hookcalls\check_hookcalls.module" at line 10. in
> C:\softwares\xampp\htdocs\d9_firstexperience\2\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage.php on line 152

Comment: Remove the closing php tag

Comment: Yes, I just removed the tags, and restarted apache it start working but it's strange. 
You can post it as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Drupal coding standards say not to add the closing PHP tag exactly to avoid that issue.

Comment: Okay, thank you I have to learn standards.

Comment: The [Coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards) guide and its sub-guides are a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Drupal coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards), the closing php tag should be omitted.

The [PHP Code Tags section](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards#phptags) of the coding standards (as well as [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1786046/6335551)) give a good overview of why it's a good practice to omit them in general:

> - Removing it eliminates the possibility for unwanted whitespace at the
>   end of files which can cause "header already sent" errors, XHTML/XML
>   validation issues, and other problems.
> - [The closing delimiter at the
>   end of a file is optional](http://www.php.net/basic-syntax.instruction-separation).
> - PHP.net itself removes the closing
>   delimiter from the end of its files (example: [prepend.inc](https://github.com/php/web-php/blob/master/include/prepend.inc)), so this
>   can be seen as a "best practice."